# Is it possible to do bitmap check point in descriptive programming? HP-UFT 14

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

Hi i would like to know if doing a bitmap check point is possible in descriptive programming since i am handling the same image in multiple pages

Comment: Hi Reid, great question. could you please give an example, and also include the HP UFT version number

Comment: hi @Dan , perfect example is in the answers below :D and also im using HP-uft 14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'Test Code
SystemUtil.CloseProcessByWndTitle("HPE MyFlight Sample Application")
SystemUtil.Run "C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\Unified Functional Testing\samples\Flights Application\FlightsGUI.exe"
Window("regexpwndtitle:=HPE MyFlight Sample Application").WaitProperty "visible",True
Window("regexpwndtitle:=HPE MyFlight Sample Application").CaptureBitmap "C:\Expected.bmp",True
Window("regexpwndtitle:=HPE MyFlight Sample Application").CaptureBitmap "C:\Actual.bmp",True
Msgbox CompareBitMapFiles("C:\Actual.bmp","C:\Expected.bmp")

Public Function CompareBitMapFiles(ByVal ExpectedImage,ByVal ActualImage)
    Dim objFileCompare
    Dim blnIsEqual
    Dim strFileComparisonValue : strFileComparisonValue = "Not Equal"
    Set objFileCompare = CreateObject("Mercury.FileCompare")
    blnIsEqual = objFileCompare.IsEqualBin(ExpectedImage,ActualImage,0,1)
    If blnIsEqual Then
        strFileComparisonValue = "Equal"
    End If
    CompareBitMapFiles = strFileComparisonValue
End Function
```

Another command line tool is [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/freeimage/?source=typ_redirect)

Answer (score 1):

HP UFT version 12.5, the standard checkpoint functions include ability to check against a bitmap:

[official HP help xenter for Checkpoints](https://uft-help.saas.hpe.com/en/14.01/UFT_Help/Content/User_Guide/z_Ch_UsingCheckpoints.htm)

[official HP help center for checkpoint bitmaps](https://uft-help.saas.hpe.com/en/14.01/UFT_Help/Content/User_Guide/Bitmap_Checkpoint_Properties_Grid_Area.htm?cshid=User_Guide%2FBitmap_Checkpoint_Properties_Grid_Area.htm)

[softwaretestinghelp.com step by step example](http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/qtp-tutorial-14-bitmap-and-text-checkpoints/)